# If an Access table has a new record selected, It displays (New). How do I get my code to recognize the (New) value?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I Want to be able to let the end user of the database know when they are on a new record, but I do not want to display the actual id's. I just want the text box to display "New" when it is a new record.

I have two buttons one the selects the previous record and the other that selects the next record. The next record button has the code that I am trying to get to work.

```
Private Sub Command25_Click()
On Error GoTo Command25_Click_Err

    On Error Resume Next
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNext

    ' I wrote this if statment to capture the (New)
    If frmQuote_QuoteID.Value = " " Then
        frmQuote_QuoteNumber.Value = "NEW"
    End If

    If (MacroError <> 0) Then
        Beep
        MsgBox MacroError.Description, vbOKOnly, ""
    End If


Command25_Click_Exit:
    Exit Sub

Command25_Click_Err:
    MsgBox Error$
    Resume Command25_Click_Exit

End Sub
```

I have also tried if frmQuote_QuoteID.value = "(New)" Then

I am trying to get this to the point where the form can display New based on an empty primary key field, but if it is not a new record then I don't want anything displayed

Comment: the text box will always contain a value you don't want to overwrite with your own text.  If you don't want them to see the IDs, then don't display the column, or hide it with a column width value of 0.  What you're trying to do is equivalent to opening a table in datasheet view and changing the values in the cells there.

Comment: I am not trying to change the value of the ID field. Also the Id field is hidden from view already. I just want a separate  text box to display "New" so I can alert the user that it is a new record, if it is not a new record than don't want anything displayed

Comment: You can do that with a label, then.

Comment: I agree, but I needed to know how to get my code to recognize the fact that it was a new record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use

```
if me.NewRecord then
```